# postgis st_geomfromgml error on point

Tags: postgis, gml

In PostGIS 2.0 I try:

```
select ST_GeomFromGML(
  '<gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992">
       <gml:pos>275466.0 565559.0 0.0</gml:pos>
   </gml:Point>');
```

This gives an error:

```
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid GML representation
SQL state: XX000
Context: SQL function "st_geomfromgml" statement 1
```

What is wrong with my point?

Comment: Your srsName looks weird.  Why not just `EPSG:28992`?  Can you try using `<gml:coordinates>275466.0, 565559.0, 0.0</gml:coordinates>` instead of `<gml:pos>...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to upgrade to the latest version of PostGIS. There is an interaction between older versions of PostGIS and the latest version of libxml2 that causes this problem.

Comment: http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2092

Comment: For now I will try hardcoding removal of "gml:" from the xml in my python script as this will be easier then asking my client to upgrade their database ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying that the point is in 3D space with:

```
<gml:pos srsDimension="3">275466.0 565559.0 0.0</gml:pos>
```

Or drop the extra coordinate (if it isn't important).